# Stack Exchange Twitter profile is out of date

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, twitter

The twitter info of [@StackExchange](https://twitter.com/StackExchange) still showing 131 Community sites (SO and 130 other). There are 168 sites are there.

I think it's been a long time since SE updated the info. Update it to correct the number.

[image: snippet of Stack Exchange Twitter profile]

Comment: Also isn't SO Careers now SO Jobs?

Comment: You'll also notice that account hasn't been *used* for over a year. That seems to be an archived account at this point. We're not gonna continue updating something that never gets used.

Comment: Any plan in future @animuson or not-use-forever ?

Comment: @OptimusPrime maybe it's because Stack Exchange Inc. [recently moved to calling itself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) Stack Overflow Inc.